# Highlight current category in wp_list_categories

Tags: categories

I am using `wp_list_categories` to display all terms of my custom taxonomy `'categories'.`

The function is outputting all my terms successfully but the current category is not being highlighted, even though `'current_category'` is set to `1` in my arguments.

The function is being outputted on `taxonomy-categories.php`, following the naming convention of my taxonomy `categories`.

It is not inside a loop, could that be why?

UPDATE, here is my function:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'               => 'term_group',
    'title_li'              =>  NULL,
    'order'                 => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'            => 1,
    'use_desc_for_title'    => 0,
    'feed'                  => '',
    'hierarchical'          => 1,
    'echo'                  => 1,
    'current_category'      => 1,
    'taxonomy'              => 'categories'
);
echo wp_list_categories($args);
```

Note: this works on my `single-{post-type}.php` template, but does not function on my `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` template.

Comment: You don't need to echo `wp_list_categories($args)` if you set the `echo` key to true. I would also try removing the `current_category` key entirely to see if that helps. It should by default, on the taxonomy template page display the current term from my understanding of it. Finally, the `wp_list_categories()` can be used anywhere be it inside or outside the loop.

Comment: Bingo! You are right. Thank you. I never thought about the echo in my arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will  add a `current-cat` class to any / all categories connected to the post, not jut one.

Add this to `functions.php`

```
function tax_cat_active( $output, $args ) {

  if(is_single()){
    global $post;

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $args['taxonomy'] );
    foreach( $terms as $term )
        if ( preg_match( '#cat-item-' . $term ->term_id . '#', $output ) )
            $output = str_replace('cat-item-'.$term ->term_id, 'cat-item-'.$term ->term_id . ' current-cat', $output);
  }

  return $output;
}
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'tax_cat_active', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This works perfectly on my `single-{post-type}.php` template. However I just realised it does not work on my `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` template. How can I get the same functionality on the taxonomy template?

Comment: For @Howdy_McGee

Comment: Could you post your `wp_list_categories()` code? It should have this functionality by default.

Comment: I have updated the question with my code.

Answer (score 4):

The answer provided by Howdy_McGee produced a PHP notice for me that prevented it from working correctly. I changed `$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $args['taxonomy'] );` to `$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonomy' );` I also added a check that the post has terms associated with it to suppress additional PHP warnings if `$terms` is empty.

```
function tax_cat_active($output, $args) {
    if (is_single()) {
        global $post;
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'category');
        if (!empty($terms)) {
            foreach( $terms as $term )
                if ( preg_match( '#cat-item-' . $term ->term_id . '#', $output ) )
                    $output = str_replace('cat-item-'.$term ->term_id, 'cat-item-'.$term ->term_id . ' current-cat', $output);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'tax_cat_active', 10, 2);
```

Comment: +1 for corrections, and for those who want to use it: add in style.css *(in your theme template folder)* `li.cat-item.cat-item-12.current-cat a{font-size: 1.5em;font-style: italic;}` (where 12 is the `Category ID` which you need to change to correct ID and the style to own wishes) Remember that you have to add as many style lines as you have categories *(with correct cat ID ofcourse)*

Answer (score 0):

Actually this functionality is already build in the `wp_list_categories` function.

Just use the `current_category` like this:

```
'current_category' => get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ) ?? null,
```

**Full example:**

```
wp_list_categories(array(
                'child_of'            => 0,
                'current_category' => get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ) ?? null,
                'depth'               => 0,
                'echo'                => 0,
                'exclude'             => '',
                'exclude_tree'        => '',
                'feed'                => '',
                'feed_image'          => '',
                'feed_type'           => '',
                'hide_empty'          => 1,
                'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
                'hierarchical'        => true,
                'order'               => 'ASC',
                'orderby'             => 'name',
                'separator'           => '<br />',
                'show_count'          => 1,
                'show_option_all'     => '',
                'show_option_none'    => __('No categories'),
                'style'               => 'list',
                'taxonomy'            => 'category',
                'title_li'            => '',
                'use_desc_for_title'  => 1,
            ));
```