# Color different for the current category

Tags: categories

I would like to change the color of the current category in this page :

[image]

my code for display category is :

```
     <ul class="ul-cat">
            <?php wp_list_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'title_li' => 'Filtres :</br></br>',

) ); ?>
```

thank you :)

Comment: What template does this code appear on? Single post, category archive ...?

Comment: in tpl_newsroom.php and category.php pls

Comment: Category.php makes sense but can you explain how "tpl_newsroom.php" would have a "current" category? Is it restricted to displaying 1 category's posts, have a different taxonomy?

Comment: This answer should take care of category.php: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121702/highlight-current-category-in-wp-list-categories

Comment: If newsroom template uses custom taxonomy: http://haxo.it/highlight-current-category-in-wp_list_categories-custom-taxonomy/

Comment: Can you post the full code for that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it will add `current-cat` class to the current category item.

If we need to change that, we can use:

> **'current_category'**
>
> (int|array) ID of category, or array of IDs of
>   categories, that should get the `'current-cat'` class. Default 0.

as mentioned in  the [dev docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) for `wp_list_categories()` arguments:

Then we can style it as needed via CSS.

**Example**

For your setup:

```
.ul-cat .current-cat a {
     color: #aaa;
}
```